# Interface dinâmica baseada em valores de um objeto (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Estou tentando realizar o seguinte:

```
interface A {
    name: string,
    type: string
}

let var_A: Array<A> = [
    {name: 'firstName', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'lastName',  type: 'string'},
    {name: 'age',       type: 'number'}
]

interface B {
    firstName: string,
    lastname: string,
    age: number
}

let var_B: Array<B> = [
    {firstName: 'José', lastname: 'Silva', age: 25},
    {firstName: 'Pedro', lastname: 'Paulo', age: 50},
]
```

Meu grande problema é: como conseguir criar a interface B dinamicamente, baseada na objeto var_A? É possível?

Comment: Uma interface dinâmica? Por quê precisa fazer isso?

Comment: Pra saber se dá pra fazer.